# Java: separate main logic & exception-handling logic

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

**Question:** *how to move all logic to strategy (another class) but leave exception-handling logic in class-owner?*

---

**I've got:** method `map` which gets `data` array from input argument, and then perform a lot of logic on that:

```
class Owner ...
public void map(final LongWritable key, final Text value, final Context context) {
    // 1st-fragment of code
    String[] data = null;
    try { // Not Owner class logic, should be moved to strategy
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(line);
        CustomParser cParser = new CustomParser(reader,_strategy);
        data = cParser.getLine();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        outputBadData(line); // Owner class logic
        return;
    }

    // 2nd-fragment of code: logic which is based on `data` array
    ................
    ................
}
```

**I want:** Actually all logic in `1st` fragment (except `outputBadData`) doesn't belong to this class. I want to move it strategies. It'll look like:

```
public void map(final LongWritable key, final Text value, final Context context) {
    // 1st-fragment of code
    String[] data = strategy.getData(value);

    // 2nd-fragment of code: logic which is based on `data` array
    ................
    ................
}
```

**Problem:** `outputBadData` is a logic of `Owner` class, not the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood right, you must create your Strategy class and define within it a method with required logic.
In this method's signature define 'throws IOException'

for example:

```
public [return type] readLine(arguments...) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Also you must have the reference to an object of your new class(Strategy) to invoke the 'readLine' method.
You can store this object as field of Owner class passing it as constructor argument (for using setter method) when you create the instance of this class. And then, in your 'map' method of Owner class, surround the 'readLine' method invocation with 'try-catch' block to handle exception:

```
try{
     strategyReference.readLine(arguments...); 

    }catch (IOException e) {
        outputBadData(line); 
        return;
```

Comment: the problem is that `strategyReference.readLine` throws an Exception and return values. Even if it throw an Exception we should proceed work with data that we had gathered before exception.

Comment: Maybe in this case it would be a better way to handle 'IOException' within 'readLine()' method in 'try-catch' blok. In 'try-catch' you can initialize  your 'data' array with BadData. And after exception handling you can return your array from this method . The 'map()' method will get the data in any case.

But the next question: is the subsequent  logic the same for correct and incorrect data? Maybe you have data validation next?